# What is this animation called?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]

So, I have a menu where I need to add a similiar effect. If anyone could explain how it works or what this is called, it would be great.

Comment: lava lamp animation. Check this [live](https://codepen.io/Patak/pen/QpLpOV) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the name of this type of animation, but, I might know how it works.

So maybe there is a div being displayed on the selected option and when any other option is clicked, the div is animated to go that option. And while in that animation state it is stretched a bit so that the animation is smoother.

**Try implementing this!**